# microsoft word - regular expression with brackets and formatting?

Tags: regex, ms-word

Trying to use regular expression in ms word see https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/PowerUser_MSOffice.html

1. How do I find all text "{text}" in the word document?  This regular expression works in a text/regex  \{(.*?)\} but it doesn't work in word.
2. Also, is there a way to auto-format this with a style if found?

Comment: For some reason, in MS Word wildcards, although `*` is listed, and you may type `{0,}`, this won't work. Thus, what you may try is `(\{[!{}]@})` and replace with `\1` and select any format you wish to apply from the left-hand bottom corner of the CTRL+H dialog.

Comment: thanks! that did it... if you can add it as answer I'll accept it so you do get credit. You wouldn't know by chance how to apply a style to these results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Word, the wildcards are somewhat limited in functionality and you cannot translate `*` quantifier exactly (`{0,}` does not work for some reason). So, what you can use is

```
(\{[!{}]@})
```

and replace with `\1`.

To apply some format or style, you need to select it in the left-hand bottom corner of the Search & Replace dialog window when your cursor is in the replacement text field.

*Pattern details*:

- `(` - start of capturing group #1

  - `\{` - a literal `{` char
  - `[!{}]@` - one or more (`@`) chars other than `{` and `}` (matched with `[!{}]`)
  - `}` - a `}` char.
- `)` - end of the group.